# Is it possible to select from selected checklist SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a query select and i need is to select the data in selected checkbox list. Is it possible?

This is my query: Im tring to use -IN- but i think this is not the solution

```
       SELECT [scod], [ecode], [scty] ,[sonm] FROM [Z_ALI].[dbo].[M_STORE]  WHERE [scod] IN ('FROMTHECHECKLIST')
```

I' trying to do like this:

```
          For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

                If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    Dim CheckRow As CheckBox = (TryCast(row.Cells(1).FindControl("chckSelector"), CheckBox))

                    If CheckRow.Checked Then
                        Dim scode As String = TryCast(row.Cells(2).FindControl("lblsstorecode"), Label).Text

                        Dim sql As String = "SELECT [scod], [ecode], [scty] ,[sonm] FROM [Z_ALI].[dbo].[M_STORE]  WHERE [scod] IN ('+scode+')"

                        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql)

                            Using dtViewing As Data.DataTable = code.GetData(cmd, "NSP", code.HRIS, "SELECT")
                                If code.err = String.Empty Then
                                    GridView4.DataSource = dtViewing
                                    GridView4.DataBind()
                                Else
                                    code.setStatus(code.err, Me.Page, "")

                                End If

                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

For example this is the selected list from checkboxlist

```
     Checklist
  -|351530928006|
  0|351530928007|
  0|351530928008|
  0|351530928009|
  -|3515309280010|

  zero is the selected
   - is not selected
```

Is it possible to get or iterate all the list from the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT scod,ecode,scty,sonm
FROM M_STORE
WHERE scod IN (Checklist(0), Checklist(1), Checklist(2)...)
```

or have your checklist in sql table and do this

```
SELECT scod,ecode,scty,sonm
FROM M_STORE
WHERE scod IN (SELECT scod FROM ChecklistTable)
```

Comment: No the checklist is not on the table but in checkbox

Comment: That's why i said use this OR that

Comment: But how to identify it on the checklist if I'm going to use OR

Comment: What i was trying to say is there are 2 ways to do this. Either use method (a) or use method (b) which i provided. Method (b) needs the values to be in an sql table.

Comment: '+scode+' will be taken AS IS cause it's in single quotes and it's not a way of doing this

Comment: you have the list and you know it's length so you can easily use method (a) i provided